# Calling function while creating form elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var a =10;
function test()
{
 if ( a ==10) {
   document.sample.checkbox1.checked = true ; 
  }

}

</script>

<form name="sample">

 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1" test();>Option

</form>
```

While creating form itself its automatically call function based on it should decide whether its need to checked or not ..

Here the question . How  to call the function without any click ( on click event )

Thanks , 
Chells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run the `test()` function in the `body`'s `onLoad` handler:

```
<body onLoad="test();">
```

This will call the function once the page's content has been loaded.

You could also just call the function in `<script>` tags after the inputs:

```
<form name="sample">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1">Option    
</form>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    test();
</script>
```

This will be called as the page is loaded.

Comment: `<body onload="...">` sets `window.onload`, ie it *WILL* wait for external resources to load! If you don't want to wait for that, you need a DOMContentLoaded listener (or use an apropriate hack in browsers which don't support the event natively)

Comment: No point in using the "language" attribute as all JavaScript-supporting browsers default to JavaScript... You'll want to use a type attribute if you want it to validate though.

Comment: Also, using the onLoad event is ONLY necessary when you need to wait for ALL resources (including images & stylesheets) to load.

Answer (score 1):

There's always good old `document.writeln()`, even if it's been succeeded by DOM manipulation in most use cases:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.writeln('<input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1"' +
    (a == 10 ? ' checked' : '') + '>');
</script>
<noscript>
 <!-- unchecked by default -->
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox1">
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to call it in the onLoad event of the body tag.  But perhaps you could explain more about *why* you want to call this function in the first place?

Comment: i just want to enable the checkbox basesd on the variable . i will move around the page then if the comee back to check box  . it should be automatically call function based on the variable it should decide .. whether i need to checked or not . ?

Answer (score 0):

As Perspx said, throw it in an event for the body's onload, but look into an event lib ([like mine](http://github.com/cbiggins/event-lib/tree/master)) because there is better support and flexibility for them than inline events.